# BigQuery Jmultiple JOINS not running

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm faily new to SQL and BQ. I'm trying to JOIN multiple tables to create a email performance report.

The first JOIN works fine, but once I add the second JOIN it takes forever to run. Yesterday I cancelled it after processing for an hour

Is there a better way to join these tables?

```
SELECT
  m.primaryAttributeValue AS email,
  m.link,
  COUNT (DISTINCT(m._airbyte_ab_id)) AS total_link_clicks,
  COUNT (DISTINCT(o._airbyte_ab_id)) AS total_opens,
    COUNT (DISTINCT(d._airbyte_ab_id)) AS delivered,
FROM
  `marketo-392003.marketo_airbyte.activities_click_email` AS m
  JOIN `marketo-392003.marketo_airbyte.activities_open_email` AS o ON m.primaryAttributeValueId = o.primaryAttributeValueId
  JOIN`marketo-392003.marketo_airbyte.activities_email_delivered` AS d ON d.primaryAttributeValueId = o.primaryAttributeValueId
WHERE
  m.activityDate >= TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01') -- Replace with your desired date range
  AND m.activityDate <= TIMESTAMP('2023-12-31') -- Replace with your desired date range
GROUP BY
  m.primaryAttributeValue,
  m.link
HAVING
 m.primaryAttributeValue LIKE '%SB%'
ORDER BY
  total_link_clicks DESC;
```